# $T$ injective $\iff T(x) = 0$ has one solution.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I am trying to prove that if $T$ is a linear map, then if $T$ is injective this implies that $T(x) = 0$ and its converse.

However I really need a push in the right directions because I dont seem to get to the answer myself. Hope someone could possible help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $T$ is injective then, by the definition of injective, the equation $T(x)=0$ can only have one solution.

And if $T$ is *not* injective, you can find two distinct vectors $v$ and $w$ such that $T(v)=T(w)$. But then the equation $T(x)=0$ has two solutions (at least): $0$ and $v-w$.

Comment: Thanks. I think I was stuck of thinking in a much too difficult way.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $T(x)=0$ has one solution, $T(x)=T(y)$ implies that $T(x)-T(y)=T(x-y)=0$, since $T(x)=0$ has one solution which is $0$, $x-y=0$ and $x=y$.

Suppose that $T$ is injective, $T(0)=0$ implies that $T(x)=0$ has a solution which is unique since $T$ is injective